# Using powershell how can I extract information froma browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I have the following PowerShell script but I would like to capture the IP address reported by the browser.  How do I do that

```
$Webs = @(
"http://geoip.hidemyass.com/",
"http://some other web address "
"http://another web address",
"http://several more web addresses"
)

foreach ($Web in $Webs) {
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$ie.visible = $true;
$ie.navigate2($Web);
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; } 
 Get-Process iexplore | Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() }
}
```

The first web address tells me what Ip address my VPN proxy is assigned at the time.  I want to capture the IP address that the browser displays and write it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty easy using PowerShell's awesome Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet.  You specify a url using the -URI param, and then it sets up a Webkit object for you and scrapes the content from the site.

The absolute best part about this is that it will ALSO parse out all of the HTML.

So, if we browse out to your website link and take a peak at the HTML, we'd see something like this:

[image: Not my actual public IP, but try to hack it if you want :P]

See that  tag?  Right there in the Title, we've got our IP address.  This is going to be so easy.  We just need to commit this $url to a variable, then look into its .ParsedHTML properties for the right tags, in this case the .title tag.

```
$url = 'http://geoip.hidemyass.com/'
$Results = Invoke-WebRequest $url 
"Your IP address is $($results.ParsedHtml.title)"
```

Which returns something like this:

[image]

This was cool, and we can take it one step further and make a function by wrapping it up like this, which works in PS v3 and up:

```
Function Get-PublicIPAddress {
$url = 'http://geoip.hidemyass.com/'
$b = Invoke-WebRequest $url 

[pscustomobject]@{IPAddress=$b.ParsedHtml.title}
}
```

Which gives us results like this:

[image]

So, you can see by these examples that if the pages you're looking at online have meaningful data within HTML tags like this, it's actually very easy to get the data back out in exactly this manner.  Let me know if you have a specific other example that you need help with.